# How does Python sort user-defined objects?

Tags: python, sorting

What's the default order for sorting user-defined objects in Python?  I know *how* to change this, using the `key` parameter or defining the `__lt__` etc, methods, but not what order you get if you don't.

Comment: You should probably start by reading the library manual before asking questions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: Sorting *what* objects?

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers the question.  And please don't make assumptions of laziness, it is rude. I spent quite a bit of time researching this before asking.

Comment: Any objects of classes you defined yourself.

Comment: 1. If you don't want people to assume you did no research, *show what research you did*. 2. An example always helps (define an object, put a few in a list, sort it, ...). 3. Which version(s) of Python?

Comment: Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result). 
...
CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Comment: Thanks @khelwood, if you put that as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Python sorts objects by default in ascending order. A simple ascending sort is done by calling the sorted() function.

It returns a new sorted list.

Comment: But how is _ascending_ defined for classes that don't have comparison methods?

Comment: @xorsyst why on earth have you accepted this answer? You pointed out *yourself* that it doesn't actually answer the question!